# Using $routeParams or $location for History Links

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I am working on a questionbank and I have nicely coded most of the elements, but I would like to add some browser history for navigating the questions.

So here is the basic setup on plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/1F64dDrxVYfD8ScVGgac/preview

Currently the page loads under `/quiz`
but I would like to `$scope.currentQ` to dynamically be changed by the url search of

```
/quiz?q=1
```

I have played around with $routeParams as an alternative and $location but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Can someone give me a helping hand?

```
// Code goes here

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('questionbank', []);
    //////////////
    //Directives//
    //////////////
    app.controller('questionbankController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.currentQ = 0;
        $scope.guess = [];
        $scope.SBAchoices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
        $scope.questions = questions;
        $scope.prevQ = function() {
            if ($scope.currentQ !== 0) {
                $scope.currentQ--;
            }
        };
        $scope.nextQ = function() {
            if ($scope.currentQ < $scope.questions.length - 1) {
                $scope.currentQ++;
            }
        };
        $scope.submit = function(guess) {
        };
    }]);
    var questions = [{
    questionid: 1,
    question: "What year is it?",
    choices: [
        "2011",
        "2012",
        "2013",
        "2014",
        "2015"
    ],
    answer: "2015",
    reason: "Because it is not yet 2016!",
    category: "test"
}, {
    questionid: 2,
    question: "Which medical school is the best?",
    choices: [
        "Kings",
        "Imperial",
        "St. George's",
        "Barts",
        "UCL"
    ],
    answer: "UCL",
    reason: "Creators are from UCL, do I need to say any more?",
    category: "test2"
}];
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with navigation based on $location service http://run.plnkr.co/50SiWpwg1VEvLo2w/?q=1 (link to code http://plnkr.co/edit/PZX9Td4y6EJEnLm2yK4H?p=preview). It's the simplest way to have navigation working based on this event:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {...})
```

Comment: This works exactly as I intended it to! I seem to understand most of the changes, but I was wondering if you could help me understand the getQuestionIndexById function.

Would not linking the `$scope.currentQ = $location.search().q` be sufficient?

Comment: For my application I am unable to use `html5Mode` and this breaks the redirect if the search is greater than the last index. I have been trying to make a fix, but to no avail.

Comment: Here is updated and simplified version with disabled html5mode http://plnkr.co/edit/yPW5e8FO4AZDHxGrXf8U?p=preview . Actually you need to use something like getQuestionIndexById to find question by its id since question index in array isn't constant, but if you sure that your "questions" array won't change later - it's ok to use indexes instead of id.